# Q: How to write a query to display unused stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

How to write a query to display unused stored procedures?

Comment: What do you mean by unused?

Comment: it mean not used since last year

Comment: have a look at this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47025/identifying-unused-stored-procedures

Comment: but i need unused SP since last one year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query to find all procedures which are not altered in last one year.

```
select ROUTINE_NAME,LAST_ALTERED 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where LAST_ALTERED < DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE())
```

You can use below query to find all procedures which are not executed in last one year.

```
SELECT o.name, 
ps.last_execution_time,DB_NAME(ps.database_id)
FROM   sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON ps.object_id = o.object_id 
WHERE  DB_NAME(ps.database_id) = 'DATABASENAME' 
and  cast(ps.last_execution_time as DATE)< DATEADD(YY,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Dear i need all procedures which are not used in last one year?

Comment: Please check now, I have added another query

Comment: Procedures that have the "WITH RECOMPILE" hint will never show up in the cache.  

When the server is restarted, that cache will be cleared.

As the cache gets filled, older plans get moved out of this table.  In the system I'm on, we have no entries in this table over 3 days old.